# Vue.js styling seems buggy after page reload

Tags: css, vue.js, styling

I was just finished styling a component. All of a sudden after reloading the page of the development server the whole styling behaved very differently (see screenshots below). Especially the styling of the parent div with the id `#searchBarMain` seemed to have disappeared and be without any effect to changes e.g. changing the padding, background, etc.

If I rename the id of this very div to something like `#searchBarMain1` and save the document everything is working properly again. But only until I reload the browser tab that my page is running in.

## Code for the component

```
<template>
  <div id="searchBarMain">
    <label id="svgIcon">
      <Dropdown
        id="dropdown"
        :options="searchItems"
        v-on:selected="setEntry"
        :disabled="false"
        name="zipcode"
        :maxItem="10"
        placeholder="Search Object"
      >
      </Dropdown>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Dropdown from "vue-simple-search-dropdown";

export default {
  name: "SearchBar",
  props: {
    searchItems: Array,
  },
  components: {
    Dropdown,
  },
  methods: {
    setEntry(entryTitle) {
      console.log(entryTitle);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#searchBarMain {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 23px;
  font-size: 0.55em;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #707070;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#searchBarMain:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}

#searchBarMain:focus {
  background: #ffffff;
}

/* Adding and positioning the search icon */
#svgIcon {
  position: relative;
}

#svgIcon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: -18px;
  background: url(../assets/svgs/searchIcon.svg);
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background-size: 13px 13px;
}

/* Search icon end */

/* This is the input field */
#dropdown .dropdown-input {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "SegoeUI-Regular";
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  outline: none;
  border-style: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 7px 10px 7px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#dropdown .dropdown-input:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}

#dropdown .dropdown-input:focus {
  background: #ffffff;
}

/* This is the dropown list containing appropriate search items */
#dropdown .dropdown-content {
  font-family: "SegoeUI-Regular";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#dropdown .dropdown-content .dropdown-item {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

#dropdown .dropdown-content .dropdown-item:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

## Screenshots of the problem

Styling before page reload:
[image: Styling before page reload]

Styling after page reload:
[image: Styling after page reload]

I can work around it by not reloading the page or renaming the id every time after it. But this is very cumbersome. Am I missing something here? Or may this be a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if you use `searchBarMain` as class name, not id. and also changing all css styles from `#searchBarMain` to `.searchBarMain`?

Comment: I have not the slightest idea why but that fixed it!
Do you know why?

Comment: I don't know exactly why. I googled it but I couldn't find out what's happening. My idea was maybe there is something with uniqueness of id ,virtual dom and the way css is loaded on the page.